# How do I get CiviCRM Mailing to submit via the API

Tags: civimail, api

I would like to send a mailing every time a content item is published. The mailing is not being saved.

I have taken the sample code from

```
sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/v3/examples/Mailing/Create.php
```

Such as

```
$ht_node = $content['htnode'];
$the_subject = t('New Hot Topic Published: ' . $ht_node->title);

// Submit it now. No fussing.
$currentTime = new DateTime();
$approval_date = $currentTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$currentTime->add(new DateInterval('PT1H'));
$schedule_date = $currentTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$msg_params = array(
  'recipient' => 'Ecological Society Member',
  'htnode' => $ht_node
);
$content_templated = $this->themeEmail($content, $msg_params);

// drupal html_to_text leaves styles in place.
$text_no_style = preg_replace('|<style.*?</style>|mis', '', $content_templated);
$plain_text = drupal_html_to_text($text_no_style);


// see sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/v3/examples/Mailing/Create.php
// See query DataObject.php 1060
$params = array(
  'scheduled_date' => $schedule_date,
  'approver_id' => 21638,
  'approval_date' => $approval_date,
  'replyto_email' => self::REPLY_TO_EMAIL,
  'from_email' => self::REPLY_TO_EMAIL,
  'from_name' => self::FROM_NAME,
  'subject' => $the_subject,
  'body_html' => $content_templated,
  'body_text' => drupal_html_to_text($plain_text),
  'name' => $mailing_name,
  'created_id' => 21638, // Contact id of mailing creator
  'header_id' => '9',
  'footer_id' => '10',
  'groups' => array(
    'include' => array(
      '0' => $to_group,
    ),
  ),
  'mailings' => array(
    'include' => array(),
    'exclude' => array(),
  ),
  'options' => array(
    'force_rollback' => 1,
  ),
  'api.mailing_job.create' => 1,
  'api.MailingRecipients.get' => array(
    'mailing_id' => '$value.id',
    'api.contact.getvalue' => array(
      'return' => 'display_name',
    ),
    'api.email.getvalue' => array(
      'return' => 'email',
    ),
  ),
);

  // Throw error to the parent. Let the controller print out the error messages.
// Throws  CiviCRM_API3_Exception
civicrm_initialize();
$result = civicrm_api3('Mailing', 'create', $params);

if ($result['is_error'] === 1) {
  throw new Exception('Error in civicrm api mailing create: ' . $result['error_message']);
}

watchdog(HOTTOPICSNOTIFY_MODULE_NAME, '%mailing-name scheduled to be sent to group %groupid an e-mail. Mailing id is %mailing_id', array(
  '%mailing-name' => $mailing_name,
  '%groupid' => $to_group,
  '%mailing_id' => $result['id'],
));
```

I have run the debugger over it. The sql that is generated is fine - even inserts a mailing if I run it.

I can see no errors being returned, in Bao/Mailing.php it sees the scheduled_date and passes the _evil_bao_validator_ test. $transaction->commit() is run.

There is no sign of this call in the civicrm_mailing table or in the mailing screens.

How do I create and run this mailing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the force_rollback block.

What is the result of the civicrm_api3 call?

Comment: Awesome. I didn't see that after hours of looking.